# Splicing element from array in react.js

Tags: css, reactjs

I want to splice element from array in my todo app. As per code the first element is getting removed even if I click 2nd or 3rd remove button. Button used for removing element invokes remove(i) function,Here is my code for todo:

```js
    class App extends React.Component {

      constructor(){
        super();
        this.state={
          todo:[]
        };
      };

      entertodo(keypress){
        var Todo=this.refs.inputodo.value;
        if( keypress.charCode == 13 )
        {
          this.setState({
            todo: this.state.todo.concat({Value:Todo, Decor:'newtodo animated fadeInLeft', checked:false})
          });
          this.refs.inputodo.value=null;
        };
      };
      todo(text,i){
        return (
          <li onClick={this.completes.bind(this,i)}className={text.Decor}>
            <input type="checkbox" onChange={this.todoCompleted.bind(this,i)}className="option-input checkbox" checked={text.checked} />
            <div key={text.id}  className="item">
              {text.Value}
              <button type="button" className="destroy" onClick={this.remove.bind(this)}>X</button>
            </div>
          </li>
        );
      };

      remove(i){
        this.state.todo.splice(i,1)
        this.setState({todo:this.state.todo})
      };
      todoCompleted(i){
        var todo={...this.state.todo}
        if(todo[i].checked){
          this.state.todo[i].checked = false;
          this.state.todo[i].Decor='newtodo'
          this.setState({
            todo: this.state.todo
          });
        }
        else {
          this.state.todo[i].checked = true;
          this.state.todo[i].Decor= 'strike'
          this.setState({
            todo: this.state.todo
          });
        }
      }; 
      allDone= ()=>{
        var todo = this.state.todo;
        
        todo.forEach(function(item) {
          item.Decor = "newtodo animated fadeInLeft strike"
        })
        this.setState({todo: todo});
      };
       completes(i){
    var todo={...this.state.todo}
    if(todo[i].Decor==='newtodo'){
      this.state.todo[i].Decor='line'
      this.setState({
        todo: this.state.todo
      });
    }
    else {
      this.state.todo[i].Decor= 'newtodo'
      this.setState({
        todo: this.state.todo
      });
    }
  };


        render() {
          return (
            <div>
              <h1 id='heading'>todos</h1>
              <div className="lines"></div>
                <div>
                  <input type="text" ref= "inputodo" onKeyPress={this.entertodo.bind(this)}className="inputodo"placeholder='todos'/>
                  <span onClick={this.allDone}id="all">x</span>
                </div>
              <div className="mainapp">
                <ul>
                {this.state.todo.map(this.todo.bind(this))}
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
          );
        }
      }  
      ReactDOM.render(<App/>,document.getElementById('app'));
```

```css
.strike {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.8/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.8/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

```js
class App extends React.Component {

  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state={
      todo:[]
    };
  };

  entertodo(keypress){
    var Todo=this.refs.inputodo.value;
    if( keypress.charCode == 13 )
    {
      this.setState({
        todo: this.state.todo.concat({Value:Todo, Decor:'newtodo animated fadeInLeft', checked:false})
      });
      this.refs.inputodo.value=null;
    };
  };
  todo(text,i){
    return (
      <li ocClick={this.completes.bind(this,i)}className={text.Decor}>
        <input type="checkbox" onChange={this.todoCompleted.bind(this,i)}className="option-input checkbox" checked={text.checked} />
        <div key={text.id}  className="item">
          {text.Value}
          <button type="button" className="destroy" onClick={this.remove.bind(this)}>X</button>
        </div>
      </li>
    );
  };

  remove(i){
    this.state.todo.splice(i,1)
    this.setState({todo:this.state.todo})
  };
  todoCompleted(i){
    var todo={...this.state.todo}
    if(todo[i].checked){
      this.state.todo[i].checked = false;
      this.state.todo[i].Decor='newtodo'
      this.setState({
        todo: this.state.todo
      });
    }
    else {
      this.state.todo[i].checked = true;
      this.state.todo[i].Decor= 'strike'
      this.setState({
        todo: this.state.todo
      });
    }
  }; 
  allDone= ()=>{
    var todo = this.state.todo;
    
    todo.forEach(function(item) {
      item.Decor = "newtodo animated fadeInLeft strike"
    })
    this.setState({todo: todo});
  };
   completes(i){
    var todo={...this.state.todo}
    if(todo[i].Decor==='newtodo'){
      this.state.todo[i].Decor='line'
      this.setState({
        todo: this.state.todo
      });
    }
    else {
      this.state.todo[i].Decor= 'newtodo'
      this.setState({
        todo: this.state.todo
      });
    }
  };

    render() {
    return (
        <div>
          <h1 id='heading'>todos</h1>
          <div className="lines"></div>
            <div>
              <input type="text" ref= "inputodo" onKeyPress={this.entertodo.bind(this)}className="inputodo"placeholder='todos'/>
              <span onClick={this.allDone}id="all">x</span>
            </div>
          <div className="mainapp">
            <ul>
            {this.state.todo.map(this.todo.bind(this))}
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    }
  }  
  ReactDOM.render(<App/>,document.getElementById('app'));
```

```css
.strike {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.8/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.8/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to pass the index to the `bind()` for `remove()`. Passing the index(`i`) fixed this. Hope it helps!

```js
class App extends React.Component {

  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state={
      todo:[],
      finished: false,
    };
  };

  entertodo(keypress){
    var Todo=this.refs.inputodo.value;
    if( keypress.charCode == 13 )
      
    {
      this.setState({
        todo: this.state.todo.concat({Value:Todo, Decor:'newtodo animated fadeInLeft', checked:false})
      });
      this.refs.inputodo.value=null;
    };
  };
  todo(text,i){
    return (
      <li ocClick={this.completes.bind(this,i)}className={text.Decor}>
        <input type="checkbox" onChange={this.todoCompleted.bind(this,i)}className="option-input checkbox" checked={text.checked} />
        <div key={text.id}  className="item">
          {text.Value}
          <button type="button" className="destroy" onClick={this.remove.bind(this, i)}>X</button>
        </div>
      </li>
    );
  };

  remove(i){
    this.state.todo.splice(i,1)
    this.setState({todo:this.state.todo})
  };
  todoCompleted(i){
    var todo={...this.state.todo}
    if(todo[i].checked){
      this.state.todo[i].checked = false;
      this.state.todo[i].Decor='newtodo'
      this.setState({
        todo: this.state.todo
      });
    }
    else {
      this.state.todo[i].checked = true;
      this.state.todo[i].Decor= 'strike'
      this.setState({
        todo: this.state.todo
      });
    }
  }; 
  allDone= ()=>{
    var todo = this.state.todo;
    var _this = this
    todo.forEach(function(item) {
      item.Decor = _this.state.finished ? "newtodo animated fadeInLeft" : "newtodo animated fadeInLeft strike"
      item.checked = !_this.state.finished
    })
    this.setState({todo: todo, finished: !this.state.finished});
  };
   completes(i){
    var todo={...this.state.todo}
    if(todo[i].Decor==='newtodo'){
      this.state.todo[i].Decor='line'
      this.setState({
        todo: this.state.todo
      });
    }
    else {
      this.state.todo[i].Decor= 'newtodo'
      this.setState({
        todo: this.state.todo
      });
    }
  };

    render() {
    return (
        <div>
          <h1 id='heading'>todos</h1>
          <div className="lines"></div>
            <div>
              <input type="text" ref= "inputodo" onKeyPress={this.entertodo.bind(this)}className="inputodo"placeholder='todos'/>
              <span onClick={this.allDone}id="all">x</span>
            </div>
          <div className="mainapp">
            <ul>
            {this.state.todo.map(this.todo.bind(this))}
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    }
  }  
  ReactDOM.render(<App/>,document.getElementById('app'));
```

```css
.strike {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.8/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.8/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for above information, did silly mistake. I need one more help. The 'x' next to input field strikes off the todo list but m not able to toggle it. Also the checkbox is not being handle

Comment: @GauravSoni I didn't get you. It works fine in my example.

Comment: i'm not talking about remove button. I'm talking about 'X' placed on right of input field, this is span element and works on 'allDone' function, I'm not able to toggle that'

Comment: @GauravSoni Updated the answer. Check

Comment: the action is working perfectly fine; thanks for that, but again on click the properties are not being toggeled

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125944/discussion-between-gaurav-soni-and-pranesh-ravi).

Answer (score 0):

You are concatenating an array with an object.

```
this.state.todo.concat([{Value:Todo, Decor:'newtodo animated fadeInLeft', checked:false}])
```

You forget a space before your `className` uses

```
onClick={this.completes.bind(this,i)} className={text.Decor}>
onChange={this.todoCompleted.bind(this,i)} className
```

In the remove function, don't use splice but concat/slice instead to avoid mutations

Comment: is there another way to achieve it?

Comment: concat is fine, you are avoiding mutations on your state

Comment: ya i understood that, i tried multiple times but not able to correct it. Also the css change on click on individual list item is not working

Comment: maybe because you forget a space onChange={this.todoCompleted.bind(this,i)}[[HERE]]className

Comment: space doesn't matter